# What significance test should I use to check whether two loss value means calculated using the same data but different imputation are different?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

As the title states, I am trying to perform a significance test between two loss value means. To give an exact idea what I want to do: I have used two imputation techniques on the same dataset. One of them serves as the baseline, the other as the potentially better method.

I have 20 loss values per method. This is because I use a train-test split and five-fold cross-validation, using four different seeds to randomise distribution of data across the folds. This same seed is also what decides the distribution of data across the train and test split. Each loss value I have is the result of applying one of the CV-trained models to my test set. Thus, for each seed, I have five loss values.

This is an example of what I mean (values are made up randomly):

| Seed | Imputation method | Loss 1 | Loss 2 | Loss 3 | Loss 4 | Loss 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | method 1 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 123 | method 2 | 15.5 | 16.5 | 17.5 | 18.5 | 19.5 |
| 345 | method 1 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 345 | method 2 | 16.5 | 17.5 | 18.5 | 19.5 | 20.5 |
| 567 | method 1 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 567 | method 2 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 789 | method 1 | 14.5 | 15.5 | 16.5 | 17.5 | 18.5 |
| 789 | method 2 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |

As I see it, I have two groups: 20 losses for my baseline method and 20 losses for my new method. What I am struggling with, is whether these groups are independent or not. In essence, there is no "influence" of one method on another method. However, both of them use the same underlying data. The latter is why I thought a paired t-test would be the way to go. However, I am not sure about this, maybe a regular t-test is correct here?

What do you think is the correct approach/significance test for this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the sample size is large the dependence between the loss values (and the seeds) should be weak and it may be ignored. However, the 'methods' are definitely paired. Thus the simplest and safest solution I see so far is to apply a paired t-test or a nonparametric alternative depending on the distribution of the sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @utobi. As the sample size is not large (I believe it is the 20 I mention), I could not ignore the dependence anyways then. I will apply a paired t-test to handle that.

Comment: By _sample size_ I mean the size of the sample to which the 5-fold CV is applied.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case it is large (assuming n>40 is large). I will still apply the paired t-test though for the sake of dependence. Thank you!